# Finding out the position of a particular key inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a class to find out the position / level of a particular key inside an array. I was actually trying to create a function but I ended up creating an entire class as I had to keep track of my counter. Although the class is working perfectly, I really need to get this done using a function only.

Could you please help me with a solution so that I can achieve the same result using function / functions only.

Here's my code for the class :

```
class Boom {

private $count = 0; 

    function get_depth($array, $keyValue)
    {   

        foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {

            if($key==$keyValue)
            {   

                return $this->count;


            }
            elseif(is_array($value))
            {
                $this->count++;                 
                echo $this->get_depth($value,$keyValue);
                $this->count--;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

To use this class:

```
$obj = new Boom();  
echo $obj->get_depth($array, 'your_key'); // 'your_key' example: 'Refrigerator'
```

You can use an array like following:

```
$asset = array(

'Electronics' => array(
                "TV"=>array("TV1"=>500,"TV2"=>2500),
                "Refrigerator"=>200,
                "Washing Machine"=>array("WM1"=>array("b1"=>array("b11"=>80,"b22"=>10),"WM12"=>10),"WM2"=>5500),
                "Savings Accounts"=>200,
                "Money Market Accounts"=>200,
                 ),
'Sports'=> array(
                "Cricket"=>array("CBat"=>500,"CBall"=>2500),
                "Tennis"=>900,
                "Football"=>array("FBall"=>1500,"FJersy"=>5500),

                ),
'Random' =>"0"                                  
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Just pass in the key on each recursive call:

```
function get_depth($array, $keyValue, $count = 0)
{
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if ($key==$keyValue) {
            return $count;
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $count++;                 
            echo get_depth($value, $keyValue, $count);
            $count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't verified the functionality of your code, I just copied your exact code in a way that does not require a class to store the variable.

Another way to do it might be to use a static variable (also not tested), but I would suggest going with the first method, above:

```
function get_depth($array, $keyValue)
{
    static $count = 0;

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if ($key==$keyValue) {
            return $count;
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $count++;
            echo get_depth($value, $keyValue);
            $count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How stupid I am. Thank you very much for your help. Its working perfectly. :)

Comment: @black_belt: Good to hear. You may also want to look at the PHP function [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists). I'm sure using that would be more efficient than looping through the array each time.

Comment: Are you trying to mean that I should use `array_key_exists` before starting to loop through the array. Thank you very much again. :)

Comment: I mean that you should use `array_key_exists` *instead of* looping through the array.

Comment: but `array_key_exists` only checks if the given key or index exists in the array, it doesn't return the position of the key.

Comment: @black_belt: Well, from what it looks like, you're not finding the *position* of the key either...since you only increment `$count` on the recursive call, you're just finding the depth in the nested array where the key was found (which is what I think you want, based on the function name). But I also just realized that you pretty much have to loop through the array anyways to check if there are any nested arrays and do the recursive call. So maybe it wouldn't be that useful.